# What is the preferred way to architect functions with coredata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

There is no shortage of tutorials on coredata, or questions here on SO about how to get started with coredata, or how to use specific parts.

My question is higher level - how should a larger project be architected with coredata?

1. Should the project keep most of the functions that deal with managed
   objects in a single class?
2. Should the functions that deal with the
   methods be static (I suppose they are called 'class methods') or
   instance methods?
3. Is it ok to pass managed objects into class
   methods from different threads?  what about if I also supply a
   context to the method?
4. Should I only be doing a single fetch for each entity when the app starts, then doing all of my searches and inserts against the context, or grabbing smaller sets of data from a fetch request as I need it?

As far as the blogosphere goes, it seems like the coredata architectures are the wild west - every man for themselves.  Any good design patterns here to follow?

Comment: Any question staring with 'what is the preferred' can not be answered since all answer will be opinions. For every answer saying this there will be an other answer saying do that. Als you answer can be answered with, what ever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: Answers are always opinions, but that doesn't mean languages and frameworks don't define best practices.  Mileage will vary, but there are always better ways to design for general cases.

Answer (score 0):

True, although some of you questions are really based on personal preference. I for one will never use a sigleton.

1. NO and YES. Yes on class to keep the connection to the context and no every controller will request its own data.
2. Using class methods requires you to either pass the context around or store it in a static. Using a static can cause problems if you need to change the context.
3. No, each thread should have it's now context. Core Data is not thread save.
4. To save memory only fetch what is needed, no sense in fetching everything at once.

I would suggest using `NSFecthResultsController` for filling things like table views.

If you are fetching data and storing it in core data I can really suggest using a separate context for inserting. Cocoanetics has a great [article about multiple context setup](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).